# Where are Vicious Weapons detailed?

Tags: dnd-5e, product-identification

Where do you find, or in what module do you find, Vicious weapons?

Answer (score 12):

The description for a *vicious weapon* can be found on:

- Page 209 of the DMG
- Page 248 of the [System Reference Document v5.1](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)
- The [Vicious Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/vicious-weapon) entry on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/)

There's a [text discrepancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101120/what-have-the-designers-said-is-the-reason-for-the-text-discrepancy-for-vicious) between the three versions - the DMG and *D&D Beyond* cites a static figure (7, the average of 2d6) while the SRD indicates to use a roll (2d6).

When this answer was initially written (June 7 2017), *D&D Beyond* and the SRD matched. Sometime between then and now (June 7 2018), *D&D Beyond* was changed to match the printed DMG.

Answer (score 9):

The description for a vicious weapon can be found on page 209 of the DMG or page 248 of the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=248).