# What is the correct damage for Vicious Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, damage

While typing up my answer for [Where are Vicious Weapons detailed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101117/where-are-vicious-weapons-detailed) I noticed there's an inconsistency with the description for Vicious Weapon between what's written in the DMG and the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf).

The DMG states:

> When you roll a 20 on your attack roll with this magic weapon, **the target takes an extra 7 damage of the weapon's type.**

Whereas the SRD says:

> When you roll a 20 on your attack roll with this magic weapon, **the target takes an extra 2d6 damage of the weapon's type.**

I checked the [DMG errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf) and there hasn't been a correction added there.

**Has this been updated elsewhere and which text is meant to be the correct damage for Viscious Weapon: 7 or 2d6?**

P.S I know the average roll of 2d6 is going to be about 7 anyway but that's not the point.

Comment: Very related to the damage roll discrepancy for *vicious weapon*: [How do critical hits and bonus damage interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139595/how-do-critical-hits-and-bonus-damage-interact)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There has not been any word of god statement on the matter...

...and the v1.1 DMG Errata (May 2016) doesn't cover it.

However, on Jun 7 '17 the [Vicious Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/vicious-weapon) entry on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/) said "2d6". As of June 7 2018 (possibly earlier), D&D Beyond was changed to match the printed DMG, "7".

### ...but it is now clear the SRD is in err.

Answer (score 3):

#### 7 extra damage.

As V2Blast outlines extensively in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/174222/62294), the SRD *is not an official rules source*. V2Blast summarizes:

> The SRD isn't an official rules resource, so material from the SRD is effectively irrelevant to rules questions (except where material from an official rules resource is identical to it). In other words, if we're limiting ourselves to "official 5e rules", this question is a moot point, because the SRD versions of spells don't exist in official rules resources.

Therefore, the version of Vicious Weapon that deals 2d6 damage is not even for the game Dungeons & Dragons 5th Edition. Therefore, a Vicious Weapon deals an extra 7 damage on a critical hit, [as printed in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/magic-items-a-z#ViciousWeapon):

> When you roll a 20 on your attack roll with this magic weapon, the target takes an extra 7 damage of the weapon’s type.