# Does Great Weapon Fighting allow the SRD version of a Vicious Weapon's 2d6 bonus to be rerolled?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighting-style

Does Great Weapon Fighting style allow Vicious weapons 2d6 bonus to be rerolled? Is it considered weapon damage? I know similar questions have been asked but need to know for this exact circumstance.

(Note: this question concerns the SRD version of a Vicious Weapon. The Vicious Weapon published in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* adds a flat 7 damage, rather than 2d6)

Comment: I added a clarifying note to the question.

Comment: Related: [What is the correct damage for Vicious Weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101120) , [What are weapon damage dice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127440)